# Statistics: Variance/Coveriance/Tracking error Finance

Tags: statistics, finance, variance, covariance

I want to find out/estimate the tracking error:

$(1/N)*Σ (R_p - 0.5b_1 -0.5 b_2)^2$

where $R_p$ is portfolio returns,

$b_1$ is benchmark one's return,

$b_2$ is benchmark two's return

The values for

$(1/N) Σ (R_p - b_1)^2$ , tracking error using benchmark one

$(1/N) Σ (R_p - b_2)^2$ , tracking error using benchmark two
are available.

What other information do I need, for example like variance or covariance to solve/estimate the above equation? Thank you.

Comment: anyone can help pls?